# Checking if variable is assigned

Tags: c#

I got simple problem, but couldn't find solution:

Is it possible to check if given variable has been assigned?

```
int i;
// stuff happens
if (someTest(i));
    i = 0;
Console.Write("now i is assigned for sure")
```

Comment: nope sorry - you could use a nullable but you wouldn't know if it was assigned null.

Comment: you could also encapsulate it in a property.

Comment: use a Property and easy

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx

Comment: [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For value types, the variable is **always** assigned. There **is** a value there of some kind. Even so, if you try to read the variable before it is assigned *the compiler will tell you* and show an error: your code will not compile.

Comment: 'throw an error' is misleading. The compiler will report an error

Comment: @pm100 I meant "throw" in the more general English sense, but you are right that it has a specific C# meaning. Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

In case of you need to know given field set or not, you can have Property to control that field. in the setter you can control it, for example in below example isSet Boolean flag is updated when the value set.  if you need to reset the flag based on another value you can add another condition in the setter.

```
private int i;
private bool isSet;
public int IProp
{
    get { return i;}
    set { isSet =true; i=value; }
}

// test 
Console.WriteLine("Is Set:" + isSet);
IProp = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Is Set:" + isSet);

//results
//Is Set:False
//Is Set:True
```